# Multiple submit buttons with unique ids

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my application, I am trying to create a form that has some text fields and a collection of attachments.  The user will have the ability to load an existing form from the database, and edit the fields and also add/remove individual attachments from the attachment collection.

For this purpose, in my view I have a foreach loop that renders the attachment details (id, name) AND also a submit button to remove the attachment.  There is also a main submit button at the bottom of the form that the user can click once they have finished editing the form.

I have followed [this solution](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/) to implement multiple submit buttons in my form.  However the problem I have is when the user wants to remove an attachment, I would need to pass the attachment ID as a parameter to the "RemoveAttachment" action when the user clicks the submit button next to the attachment.  But as it is, the application passes the main form ID to the RemoveAttachment action.  Is there a way to pass the attachment ID when the user clicks the button?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little javascript, first add a hidden field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="attachmentID" id="attachmentID">
```

Then, on each of the submit buttons:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('attachmentID').value='@ATTACHMENT_ID'" />
```

Of course, you replace ATTACHMENT_ID with whatever variable contains the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate `<form>` for each remove button, with a hidden input (or URL parameter) specifying the ID.

Beware that `<form>`s cannot be nested.